# How to change polygon display/symbol properties in QGIS while digitizing?

Tags: qgis

I have two questions. It would be great if anyone help me to sort this out. Thanks in advance

1) While capturing a polygon in QGIS, how to remove the red - shade - sort of thing..... ?

2)Though the symbol of the polygon has been set as **No brush - Solid line** .....  While using split tool and when we select the polygon..it's get selected as a whole yellow fill. So if there is background layer which i'll be using as the reference layer to split the polygon...i can't see that one.

Split tool works even without selecting the particular polygon. But i wanna know..is it possible to set the select properties like..a simple No fill - Red Solid line ?

[image]

Comment: try setting the layers' transparency also to 50%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can change the opacity of the red shading by going to Settings > Options > Digitizing > Line Color (under "Rubberband") and changing the "Alpha Channel" - lower values are more transparent
2. Similarly, you can change the default yellow selection by going to Settings > Options > Canvas & Legend > Selection Color > and changing the "Alpha Channel" to modify the transparency and/or change the color

**Note:** 2) does not seem to work in QGIS 2.2.0 in Windows, but I think this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks Darren.. Alpha channel...It didn't occur to me...